# Fine-tuning of OpeanAI model with unsupervised set, not supervised

Tags: openai-api, pre-trained-model, gpt-3, fine-tuning

I want GPT-3 model to know everything about my domain area, for example my inbox. I want to be able to ask it questions like "Have I even had a Silicon Valley Bank account?" and get correct response. I've familiarized myself with [fine-tuning mechanism](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning) in official OpenAI docs and it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I want to just dump all my emails on the model and ask it: "Learn!". However fine-tuning require supervised style learning with prompts and reponses, which I do not have. [Example](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/example-notebooks) in the notebooks for doc suggests that you can use "Davinci-instruct to ask a few questions based on a Wikipedia section, as well as answer those questions, based on that section", which I guess solves my problem if I apply it to all my emails, but I'd rather not do this step, because I might screw up something. Can I have other options?

I found that Azure Open AI integration [allows you to do fine-tuning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/fine-tuning?pivots=programming-language-studio) as well, but it seems to have the same problem.

I might be calling what I want to do is fine-tuning, but in fact I keep pre-training process and just decided to go with fine-tuning because it has documentation and API. On the other hand fine-tuning guaranties that I would get wrong answers, pre-training doesn't, and you dont want to get wrong answer on question "Have I even had a Silicon Valley Bank account?"

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate training set of prompt/completion pairs based on your knowledge base via various techniques such as:

- summarizations (for example via GPT models);
- generated Q/A via GPT;
- cloze-style questions (again you can utilize GPT itself to suggest such questions);

Use augmentations (paraphrasing, word substitutions, changing the order of sentences).